# Is postgres 9.5+ on conflict(primary key) faster than where not exists?

Tags: postgresql

Let's say you have any insert query as below -

```
insert into abc select * from def dd where not exists (select 1 from abc aa where aa.id = dd.id);
```

Vs

```
insert into abc select * from def dd on conflict(id) do nothing;
```

which one is faster?

Both tables are really large and the idea is to not insert if there is a conflict with the primary key

Comment: The second one should be faster, but why don't you benchmark it?

Comment: In your example, I would expect the latter to be faster. But if your select is actually more complex (and include multiple joins for instance), eliminating rows right from the start is probably faster, though depending on the sizes of the two tables, it could make sense to use `WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM abc)`.

Comment: They are different (the result is different), so comparing their performance makes no sense.

Comment: I'd really like to see a benchmark on this. My instinct would be that the latter could be slower if it relies on row-by-row validation of the new records, if the former could use a hash anti-join to more efficiently identify the rows that would match. If so, this would imply that no general rule would be possible, as it would depend on the execution plan of the former option.

Comment: Consider both tables really large

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Which is faster is not really relevant.  Actually, both should be very comparable, because both will be looking up the value using a unique index.

More important is that `NOT EXISTS` is not semantically correct.  Race conditions could cause two queries to both fail the `NOT EXISTS` . . . and then both would try to insert the same value.

So, for safety, I strongly advise using the `ON CONFLICT` formulation.  It ensures that the database ensure the consistency of the data.

Comment: `NOT EXISTS` will still attempt to insert duplicates if these exists in the source (tables), and fail. `ON CONFLICT IGNORE` will insist (and succeed) on inserting/updating them, in an undefined order.

Comment: The idea is to not insert if the row already exists - i.e. conflict with primary key

Answer (score 2):

Which is faster often depends on specifics.  A blanket answer is not usually possible.  And while they are subtly different they are close enough that they may be substitutes in a given circumstance.

The first is an antijoin while the second is a simple select with instructions to continue on conflict.  This means that the planner may be able to use information to effectively run it faster.   So in general, NOT EXISTS should perform better.

But this is not always the case.  If the two tables are big enough, you might have a more expensive join strategy and that could be a problem.